# ARToolkit buildToolsVersion not found

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, artoolkit

This is build.gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    model {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion = 23
            buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

            defaultConfig.with {
                applicationId = "org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimpleNativeCars"
                minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
                targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
                versionCode = 1
                versionName = "1.0.2"
                buildConfigFields.with {
                    create() {           
                        type = "int"     
                        name = "VALUE"
                        value = "1"     
                    }
                }

                ndk.with {
                    moduleName = "ARSimpleNativeCars"
                }
            }
        }

        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
            }
        }

        android.productFlavors {
        }

        android.sources {
            main.jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/nop']
                }
            }
            main.jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
                }
            }
        }

        android.compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
        //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' 
        compile project(':aRBaseLib')
    }
```

This is top level build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is an `ARToolkit` sample android project that I'm trying to run
Whenever I try to run this project it says that

```
Gradle 'ARSimpleNativeCarsProj' project refresh failed

Error: Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' <---- in this line it is actually

apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application' which if I kept it keep saying
failed to find plugin com.android.model.application
```

but if I remove model from the plugin part
It says buildToolsVersion is not specified.

Thanx for help in advance...

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to keep the model. The model refers to the new experimental gradle plugin that supports native code within Android Studio. For more details see here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

If you remove the model it cannot find the buildToolsVersion because the old (current) gradle version does not have the 'model' in the DSL. Hence you would need to remove the complete 'model{ ... }' section from your gradle.build file. But you need that because otherwise you cannot build this project. (So this is just a side note)

Also your top level gradle file should actually look like this

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
```

I'm wondering why you have another gradle version in yours.

Besides this please give this documentation a read to get started with Android development using native C/C++ code and the NDK:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_native

Let me know if this helps